# Selenium: How to upload file, if file input element appears subsequently in the DOM after file dialog is opened?

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload

I have te following problem using Selenium and Java:

I want to upload a document. I know, that I have to sendKeys to the file input field. Bu the problem is, there is no file input field in the DOM. I do not mean, that it is hidden or disabled. When I press the "chosse file" button, then the file dialog is opened. When I close this dialog, suddenly the file input field appears in the DOM. So I have to click on the choose file button with selenium, then close the dialog to be able to sendKeys to the file input element. But how can I do that, without using Java Robot Class?

Answer (score 0):

There is a process integrating AutoIT with selenium without using the Java Robot Class.

Can you please share the test URL, so that I can replicate your scenario and can provide you with a more specific resolution.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Unfortunately, I cannot give you any URL because it is a testsystem in the company I am working in and access from outside is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without closing the dialog box, you can upload file  from the dialog box.
Try this code:

```
StringSelection ss=new StringSelection("file path ");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss,null);
```

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work. After the dialog box is openened, I executes your code but nothing happens, the dialog box is still opened the whole time and the tests goes on..

Comment: Can you try giving some time with Thread.sleep() after this code and give the full path file you want to upload (like "file-path/filename.jpg")